# Redirect the output of a query in a file

Tags: bash, sql

What can I do to redirect the query result in a text file in `sqlplus`

I tried:  `start requete.sql > resultat.txt` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing shell and `sqlplus` commands. `sqlplus` doesn't understand redirections, you have to use the `spool` keyword.

For instance:

```
SQL> spool /tmp/result.txt
SQL> start requete.sql
SQL> spool off
```

From shell:

```
$ sqlplus scott/tiger @requete.sql > /tmp/result.txt
```

Comment: but how i find the file resultat:txt. i need an existing file not a temporary file

Comment: I've written `/tmp/result.txt` but the path is up to you. Just replace `/tmp/result.txt` by `/path/to/the/file/you/want.txt`. It's the same for the `start` or `@` keywords: `@/path/to/you/file.sql`

Comment: i have a problem spool dosen't work

Comment: Impossible. Even if you specfied a path whose access is denied, you'd get an error. Note that when you use `spool` and specify no more options, the result of query is also displayed on your screen. You'll have to give more info than just "doesn't work".

Comment: this is the error:   `SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "/resultat.txt"`

Comment: It cannot create the file because you try to write in the root (`/`). At this place, only the user `root` is allowed to create files and directories. Specify a path where your user has enough rights (in his home directory for instance)